# The method 'getString' was called on null inFlutter

Tags: rest, api, flutter, dart

I create multi screen form in Flutter. From first screen i save my data from forms with `SharedPreferences` in this way:

my `basic_screen.dart`

```
  saveData() async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString('firstNameForm', firstNameController.text);
    sharedPreferences.setString('lastNameForm', lastNameController.text);
    sharedPreferences.setString('emailForm', emailController.text);
  }
```

my ui:

```
  Widget _buildFirstName() {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
      width: 0.8 * width,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'IMIĘ',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(136, 136, 136, 1)),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: firstNameController,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(136, 136, 136, 1)),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide()),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Pole wymagane';
              } else
                return null;
            },
            onSaved: (String value) {
              _firstName = value;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and on my button `NEXT` i use:

```
        onPressed: () {
          if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            return;
          }
          saveData()
           Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PasswordScreen()));
        },
```

on my second screen `password_screen.dart` i create an function to rest api request:

my rest api request:

```
  createUserRequest(String firstName, lastName, email, accountName, password) async{
    Map data = {
      "firstName":firstName,
      "lastName":lastName,
      "email":email,
      "accountName":accountName,
      "password":password
    };

    var jsonResponse;
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/';
    var response = await http.post(url, body:data);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      print(jsonResponse);     
    }else{
      throw new Exception("Not send data");
    }
  }
```

and my UI with `FutureBuilder`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
        .copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

    return FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Scaffold(
            body: CircularProgressIndicator()
          );
        }
      return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: _headerSection())
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildAccountName(),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        _buildPasswordOne(),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        _buildPasswordTwo(),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        _infoText(),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        new Container(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 55.0,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                createUserRequest(sharedPreferences.getString('firstNameForm'),
                                                  sharedPreferences.getString('lastNameForm'),
                                                  sharedPreferences.getString('emailForm'),
                                                  _accountNameController.text,
                                                  _passwordOneController.text
                                                  );
                              },
                              child: Text("ZAŁÓŻ KONTO",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              shape:
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                              color: Colors.red,
                            )
                          )
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        _helpText(),
                      ],
                    ))
              ]))),
      );
    }
    );
  }
```

and in this point i have a problem, 
after click on my `RaisedButton` where is my `createUserRequest` function my console throw me this type of error:

```
The method 'getString' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getString("firstNameForm")
```

Have anybody any idea why I have this error?

Comment: From where did this `sharedPreferences` come (in password_screen) ?

Comment: ```SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
``` i create this in passwrd_screen

Comment: But you are not initialising it anywhere. Initialise that `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sharedPreferences` is not instantiated. That's the problem. You'll have to instantiate it before calling createUserRequest.

EDIT :

You can try something like below :

```
createUserRequest(string accountName, string password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    firstName = sharedPreferences.getString('firstNameForm');
    ....
    ....
    Map data = {
      .....
}
```

EDIT 2 : Another approach -

Define a global variable

```
SharedPreferences _prefs ;
```

Add a function in the initState()

```
@override
  void initState() {
    sharedPrefs();
}
```

Instantiation :

```
Future<void> sharedPrefs() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

Note : I wrote the code directly in the text editor. You might need to alter it a little bit.